# Return Names of Worksheets that Contain A Specific Text

Tags: excel, vba

This code will take every worksheet name in the active workbook and populate them in HTML format into an email.

I would like to only return sheets that contain certain text. Let's say "Cat" for example. If "Cat" does reside within the sheet, it will always be under Column D in any given sheet.

```vb
Sub Floppa()

    Dim EmailItem  As Object
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Dim wks As Worksheet, strName As String
   
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        strName = strName & wks.Name & "<br>"
    Next
    
    On Error Resume Next

    With xMailOut
        .Display
        .Subject = "Big Floppa"
        .To = "Gregory@caracal.com"
        .HTMLBody = strName
    End With
    
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am thinking of an if or for loop near `strname`.

Comment: Is the text always located in the same place within each sheet?

Comment: Yes, it will always be located in Column D in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the range method Find inside your loop, and add your list items conditional on finding the word 'cat':

```
For Each wks In Worksheets
 If Not wks.Range("D:D").Find _
       (What:="Cat", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
     strname = strname & wks.Name & "<br>"
 End If
Next wks
```

Find method is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find